# Do I need Hibernate-JPA 2.0 dependency in pom.xml for JBOSS 5 container?

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, jboss, java-ee-5

In one of the modules that we use, it has only `Entities` and this is used across different modules,
the dependency for `hibernate` in Entities module is declared in `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

what does this mean?

I thought we are using `JPA 2.0 API` and the underlying implementation is `hibernate V1.0.1`.

My colleague said we have this dependency for compile time scope because JBOSS AS 5 (which is our application server) provides the hibernate dependency (which is version > 3.4 I guess).

The question I had is why in the above dependency 1.0.1 and not that of JBOSS's hibernate version.
my colleague said it does not matter. But I don't understand why? I am sure JPA2.0 API will not be compatiable with hibernate 1.0.1. so am I really using JPA 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the version 1.0.1 of JPA 2.0. The version 1.0.1 is the JAR version, not what the code implements.

It is JPA 2 (code) with jar version 1.0.1.

------- Update 1

If you do not send any implementation you will be using JPA 1. I found this: https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673 that says that JBoss EAP 5 uses JPA 1.

If you send only the API you will use the current JPA implementation of the server.

Comment: how do I know what hibernate version I am using?

Comment: If I send only the API, there will be problem, becuase I compile for JPA2.0 and as you mentioned JBOSS EAP5 uses JPA1. (but I am using JBOSS AS5, which is equivalent of JBOSS EAP6)

Comment: You will have problem if you use JPA 2 methods. If you do not use, e.g., TypedQuery but use QUery instead you will have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

In most apps servers you can override the provided versions. Not sure of exact mechanism for JBoss however this might help:

http://www.openscope.net/2010/07/15/setting-up-a-jboss-instance-v5-x-class-loading/

So, to avoid any issues, bundle the api and implementation jars in your WAR and configure the server by whatever means provided so these local jars take precedence.